# On atoms, diatomic and triatomic molecules - Vaisheshika Sutra

Tags: science, kanada, vaisheshika, shad-darshana, vaisheshika-sutra

[Vaisheshika Sutra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vai%C5%9Be%E1%B9%A3ika_S%C5%ABtra) is the most prominent text of the Vaisheshika school of thought, one of the [Shad Darshanas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dar%C5%9Bana) in Hinduism. It was written by *[Maharshi Kanada](http://firstip.org/legendary-scientists/maharshi-kanada-the-propunder-of-atomic-theory600-bce).*

This [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanada_(philosopher)) article says that it talks about atoms, diatomic molecules and triatomic molecules.

I would like to know the Shlokas where these are mentioned, if anyone has read the text.

Comment: You should look for books or translations on the treatise. SE is not an appropriate place for this question, since you are basically asking for the work to be reproduced here.

Comment: Shankardig
an adherent of the school of Kanada, which holds that there 
are six categories, approached the Acharya and declared, "**In our 
philosophy, two atoms together form into a new atom of subtlety 
called Dvayanuka (doubled atom). If you are omniscient, tell me 
what is it that unites the two ~u's or atoms into one unit. If you 
cannot give a correct answer, then your claim for omniscience is 
only a bluff publicised by your disciples." Sankara replied, "That 
unity is due to something inherent in the atoms.**" The glorifiers
of Kanada then withdrew, saying that the Acharya was correct.

Comment: @moonstar2001 That comment just shows your ignorance about the text. Most of the text deals with issues of spiritual progress, Brahman etc. There is a specific section devoted to (with a few chapters) padartha. I am asking about that and not the whole text. Also, I do not have time right now to go through the whole section, hence this question.

Comment: @Tezz Thanks for the comment, but this post is not about views opposing Kanada. That can be asked in a separate question.

Comment: @Amit Saxena Adi Shankara here isn't opposing Kanada... He is answering as per their theory thus proving his omniscience... so what Adi Shankara says there is answering in their theory to sit in Kashi Sarvagya(Omniscience) Pitham.... and that is accordance to modern science....

Comment: @Tezz Okay, this question is also not about Adi Shankara's response to Kanada. Do you see what I am saying?

Comment: @Amit Saxena I see... you are asking slokas... That's why I made those statements as comments... otherwise I would have already put them in answer...

Comment: @Tezz Okay.....

Comment: Whether it is the whole text or a part of the text you want reproduced, the question is not appropriate. You don't have the time but people of the SE are expected to expend their time to extract passages and type them out here for you? Of all the...

Comment: @moonstar2001 Maybe you should read my question again, I am only looking for specific Shlokas from that section, assuming someone has read it already.

Comment: @moonstar2001 "You don't have the time but people of the SE are expected to expend their time to extract passages and type them out here for you?" That is quite literally a core purpose of the site: people with less knowledge of Hindu scripture post a question in the hope that people with more knowledge of Hindu scripture can share their knowledge with them.  That's entirely appropriate here.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I agree but the author's problem is not lack of knowledge but "lack of time". It is equivalent to farming out one's homework to someone else. Any case, I rest.

Comment: On a lighter note, "Time is Knowledge, Knowledge is Time" :P